# How to calculate Prob > chi2 in R to test model fit of conditional logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, chi-squared-test, survival, p-value

I used the clogit function (from the survival package) to run a conditional logistic regression in R with a big dataset of 1:M matched pairs with n=300368964 and number of events= 39995.

```
model <- clogit(Alliance ~ OVB + CVC + BVB + strata(Strata), method="exact")
```

I received following results:

```
                 coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)       z Pr(>|z|)    
OVB        -0.0498174  0.9514031  0.0166275  -2.996  0.00273 ** 
BVB         0.0277405  1.0281289  0.0304956   0.910  0.36300    
CVC         1.1709851  3.2251683  0.1089709  10.746  < 2e-16 ***
EarlyStage -1.3215824  0.2667129  0.0205851 -64.201  < 2e-16 ***
AvgVCSize   0.0087976  1.0088364  0.0002035  43.224  < 2e-16 ***
NumberVC    0.0643579  1.0664740  0.0034502  18.653  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Rsquare= 0   (max possible= 0.001 )
Likelihood ratio test= 6511  on 6 df,   p=0
Wald test            = 6471  on 6 df,   p=0
Score (logrank) test = 6801  on 6 df,   p=0
```

Since Rsquare equals 0 and the test ratios seems very high, I tried to plot the results to check whether the model fits. But I wasn't able to plot it properly.

I would online many papers which use the ratio Prob > chi2 = 0 from Stata as test ratio to proof the model fit.

How could I calculate this ratio in R? Are there any other ways I could check the model fit of my clogit results?

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks you very much in advance.

Comment: Your $n$ is a third of a billion observations and you have 40K events. It's not remotely surprising your p-values are all zero, even though the model doesn't explain a lot of the variation (& how is $R^2$ defined here?). I have no idea what you mean by "use the ratio Prob > chi2 = 0 ... as test ratio to proof the model fit". First, you don't 'prove' a model fit, and secondly, your initial expression is unclear. Prob-*what* is greater than $\chi^2$-*what*? Are you referring to the p-value for one of the model hypothesis tests? What about it? A low p-values doesn't imply the model is a good fit.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear expression. Prob is the  probability of obtaining the chi-square statistic given that the null hypothesis is true.  In other words, this is the probability of obtaining this chi-square statistic (6511) if there is in fact no effect of the independent variables, taken together, on the dependent variable.  This is the p-value, which is compared to a critical value, perhaps .05 or .01 to determine if the overall model is statistically significant.

Comment: If the p-value would be less than .000, I could say that the model is statistically significant. Is there maybe also a way to infer from the given model hypothesis tests whether the model could be significant? Or does the high number of observations compared to the events make it very unlikely that the model is statistically significant?

Comment: p-values are conditional probabilities - they *can't ever* be less than zero. It sounds like your understanding of p-values (and statistical significance) is wrong.

Comment: With "less than .000", I meant that the p-value is very close to 0. I found the explanantion for the logit estimates [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/output/stata_logistic.htm).

Comment: To be significant, your p-value should be less than your significance level, but you haven't mentioned one. The explanation of "Prob > chi2" that you linked to? It's *wrong*. But at least now I understand what it is you're talking about there - p-values for the statistics (which have asymptotic chi-square distributions). The R output in your question *already has that information*. You shouldn't try to learn what you're doing from that document, because the parts that aren't actually wrong, you seem to have misinterpreted.

Comment: I added the parameter estimates to my post. There the significance level is 0,05. What would be the right interpretation of the model hypothesis test values of my output?

Comment: There are *nine* p-values in your output. Are you honestly asking me to go through and explain how to compare each individual one to a significance level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the diagram below, the parts on the right are from the document you linked, and the parts on the left are in your output in your question. I have marked corresponding parts with the same colors (the values won't be the same in this case because they're for different data sets):

[image]

Now, the thing in green is called the likelihood ratio test statistic. For sufficiently large sample size it has approximately a chi-square distribution.

The thing in red is called the p-value. It is not correctly defined in the Stata information you linked. It is the probability of getting a chi-square value *at least* as large as the one you observed if the null hypothesis were true. It is correctly defined in the first sentence [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value).

You decide significance by comparing the p-value with your significance level. (You haven't said what significance level you're using.)

Comment: Since most of my parameter estimates were statistically significant for p=0,05, I thought my significance level is 0,05. But I do not really what the significance level of the likelihood ratio test is for me. Where could I find that out? The [study I'm replicating](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2008.01354.x/full) uses _Prob > χ2= 0.000_ to show that their model is statistically significant. Thus I think my model should be significant as well. Is this conclusion reasonable?

Comment: You don't discover what your significance level is - it's like when you drive your car somewhere; you don't find out what your destination is after you get in and drive about a while, it's something you figure out before you pick up your keys. The significance level - your type I error rate - is a deliberate choice you make before you begin your analysis (and hopefully, before you even begin to collect data).